# Is there an API for WebSphere Platform Messaging (WPM)?

Tags: java, websphere, messaging, platform, wpm

I am looking for API for WebSphere Platform Messaging (WPM), specifically for Java.

[IBM's article about WPM](http://viperrin.free.fr/WASV6/wf3816v16.pdf) reads that WPM and MQ are separate products and that WPM is available through MQ link. However, such approach is unacceptable for me.

I didn't find neither documentation nor any-language-API for WPM. Please suggest one.

Comment: @Erick, thank you for title correction

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere platform messaging (also called SIBus) is typically used via the JMS API.